# Q- spread dataset by condition (two period of time) and fill a new column (time between both periods)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
 o<- data.frame(country = c("US", "Mexico"), start = c(1972, 1982), end= c(1975, 1986))
```

I want to spread out the dataset according to the number of years, and reshape the dataset, so at the end I could have something like this:

```
a<- seq(1972, 1975, 1)
b<- seq(1982, 1986, 1)
on<-data.frame(country = c(rep("US", 4),rep("Mexico", 5)), year = c(a,b))
```

I do not know how to proceed to obtain the expected outcome just described in the code.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` with `stack`.  By using `Map`, we get the sequence of each value of 'start' to the corresponding 'end', then set the names of the `list` output as `country` column and convert the `list` to a two column `data.frame` with `stack`

```
res <- stack(setNames(Map(`:`, o$start, o$end), o$country))[2:1]
colnames(res) <- c("country", "year")
all.equal(res, on)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

If there are other columns as well, then we can change the approach slighly different by getting a `list` with `Map`, then use the `lengths` to find the `length` of each `list` element, replicate the rows of the dataset using that, and finally `cbind` the `unlist`ed `list` output as 'year'

```
o <- data.frame(id = 1:2, country = c("US", "Mexico"), 
           start = c(1972, 1982), end= c(1975, 1986)) 
lst <- Map(`:`, o$start, o$end)
res1 <- cbind(o[rep(seq_len(nrow(o)), lengths(lst)), 1:2], year = unlist(lst))
row.names(res1) <- NULL
```

Comment: hi @akrun! I have also an "id" column  in which, for instance, for the number of cases in the code above is assigned the number 1. I would like to fill in the same way as you did with years. I do not know how to do it with Map with stack

Comment: @Adriandelriorodriguez  If there are multiple columns then try `lst <- Map(':', o$start, o$end);  cbind(o[rep(seq_len(nrow(o)), lengths(lst)), 1:2], year = unlist(lst))`  Here i assumed 'id' as the 1st column and 'country' 2nd

Answer (score 0):

Using *tidyr* functions, you could first `gather` that dataset into a long format and then use `complete` on a dataset grouped by Country to fill in the years per Country.

`dplyr::select` is used to remove the extra variable representing the "start" and "end" grouping.

```
library(tidyr)

gather(o, time, years, -country) %>%
    dplyr::select(-time) %>%
    dplyr::group_by(country) %>%
    complete(years = full_seq(years, period = 1))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I do like your codes since I am using dplyr and tidyr in to change my datasets :)

Comment: hi @aosmith, I have also a "id" column  in which, for instance, for the number of cases in the code above is assigned the number 1. I would like to fill in the same way as you did with years. I do not know why when I tried to do this 'complete(years = full_seq(years, period = 1), id= id)` or 'complete(years = full_seq(years, period = 1), id= full_seq(id, period =1)` do not work

Comment: I'm not sure without an example, but possibly see `fill` from *tidyr*.  You could ask a new question with a new example.